# laravel database model "with" function

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm new in Laravel please me.

I'm working on laravel project which is already done by other developers.
I am stuck in Model::with function.

```
QxAppDetail::with(['qx_app_translation', 'qx_app_pages.qx_page_translation',
                    'user_app_info' => function($query) use($device_registration_id) {
                        $query->where('device_registration_id', $device_registration_id);
                    }])->selectRaw($this->table . '.app_id, '
                        . 'if(qx_app_details.app_icon = "", "", CONCAT("' . $this->app_icon_path . '","/", qx_app_details.app_icon)) as app_icon, '
                        . 'if(qx_app_details.download_link="","",CONCAT("' . $apk_url . '",qx_app_details.download_link)) as download_link,'
                        . $this->table . '.open_link, qx_app_details.package_name, qx_app_details.qeexo_default_app, qx_app_details.service_id,qx_app_details.sort_order,qx_app_details.is_enabled')
                ->orderBy('qx_app_details.sort_order', 'ASC')
                ->whereIn('qx_app_details.device_registration_id', array(0, $device_registration_id))
                ->get();
```

in above query i need to concat url with column like

```
'if(qx_app_details.download_link="","",CONCAT("' . $apk_url . '",qx_app_details.download_link)) as download_link,'
```

in qx_app_pages. but i'm not able to do this.

qx_app_pages and qx_page_translation are tables

Current Query output is:

```
[{"app_id":472,"app_icon":"","download_link":"","open_link":"","package_name":"com.android.settings","qeexo_default_app":"0","service_id":"9","sort_order":"0","is_enabled":"1","qx_app_translation":[{"locale":"en_US","app_name":"Settings","app_description":""}],"qx_app_pages":[{"page_id":213,"page_icon":"iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAGYAAABmCAMAAAAOARRQAAAApVBMVEX\/\/\/80d+D09PQ1dNb+\/v79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\nu3NIeXduNPbMcf\/rL31v8D+2OXl\/9El2FQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==","action":"com.android.settings","app_id":"472","qeexo_default_page":"0","is_deleted":"0","qx_page_translation":[{"page_name":"Home","locale":"en_US"}]}],"user_app_info":{"order_id":391,"device_registration_id":"11862","app_id":"472","default_page_id":"213","sort_order":"0","qeexo_default_app":"1","is_enabled":"1"}}]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the value of `qx_app_details.download_link` in your database for the current query output record?

Comment: Why do you want to do this operation in SQL? Why don't you use an Eloquent mutator to change the attribute in PHP when it's set to the `QxAppDetail` instance?

Comment: i want this with query.

Comment: How we use Eloquent mutator , Please help me

Comment: You can define a function in your `QxAppDetail` model `setDownloadLinkAttribute($value) { $this->attributes['download_link'] = config('APK_URL') . $value; }`. I don't know where your $apk_url come from but you can get it from the config of you application or via `env()` if it's a constant

Comment: let me try this

Comment: Hi i just create function public function setPageIconAttribute($value) { 
  $this->attributes['page_icon'] = 'vishal'; 
 }
here page_icon column in "qx_app_pages" table. Its not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122502/discussion-between-vishal-kamal-and-thibaud-dauce).